# jquery carousel slider with multiple image of the same image

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I want to make a slider in jquery for watches which have one main image in the centre and 3 different images(from multiple angle) of the same watch above the same. I search for multiple jquery carousel slider but maximum what I got it one thumbnail attached with one image. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: please find the same on
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/mitajakom/59ULy/3/)

I need to add more images for each single watch of different angle.